# Set flag=0 for all initial obsverations having units= 0 by group

Tags: sas

I need help in SAS or PROC SQL. I have a table like the following:

| prod_id | store_id | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 0 |
| 1 | 300 | 0 |
| 1 | 300 | 1 |
| 1 | 301 | 0 |
| 1 | 301 | 2 |
| 1 | 301 | 0 |
| 2 | 301 | 0 |
| 2 | 301 | 1 |
| 2 | 301 | 0 |
| 2 | 301 | 4 |
| 2 | 301 | 5 |
| 2 | 302 | 0 |
| 2 | 302 | 1 |

I want table should be

| prod_id | store_id | units | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 300 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 300 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 301 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 301 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 301 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 301 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 301 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 301 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 301 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 301 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 302 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 302 | 1 | 1 |

if for any store_id the oberveration starts with zero set flag =0 until first observation for that store and product id.
in short, Just set flag=0 for every store_id and prod_id untill we have first observation which is non-zero.

I tried this but it just detect first non zero obs not remaining.

```
data have;
input prod_ID store_id units;
cards;
1       300     0
1       300     0
1       300     1
1       301     0
1       301     2
1       301     0
2       301     0
2       301     1
2       301     0
2       301     4
2       301     5
2       302     0
2       302     1
;
run;
data want;
 set have;
 by store_id;
 if first.store_id then n=0;
 if units ne 0 then n+1;
 flag=ifn(n=1 and units ne 0,1,0);
 drop n;
run;
```

Comment: What have you tried?  It's also not really clear what the requirement is; but in any event, we need your code to help you with your code.

Comment: @joe I just added my code and updated my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to `retain flag`, and then don't calculate it every time, just set it to 1...

```
data want;
 set have;
 by prod_id store_id;
 retain flag;
 if first.store_id then flag=0;
 if units gt 0 then flag=1;
 drop n;
run;
```

I also add `prod_id` to the by list, as I think that's correct - you don't want 301 to keep the flag=1 from prod_id 1.